# windows azure upload file path error: 'Could not find file... '

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I've been trying to upload a file to the **Azure storage container**.
When I run my web app locally, if file is **not** in the web site **root** I get an **error**:

```
Could not find file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\test.txt'.
```

If I **copy** the file to the **web app root folder**, it works fine.

Running **web app** on the **cloud** I get an **error**:

```
Could not find file 'D:\Windows\system32\test.txt'.
```

I can't get the **full local file path** from **HttpPostedFileBase** object.

The **code**:

```
private string UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase file, string folder)
    {
        try
        {
            var date = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyyMMdd-hhmmss-");
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);

            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName=test;AccountKey=asdfasfasdasdf");
            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient(); 
            CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(folder);
            bool b = container.CreateIfNotExists();

            CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(date + fileName);
            blockBlob.Properties.ContentType = file.ContentType;

            using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(fileName))
            {
                blockBlob.UploadFromStream(fileStream);
            }
            return blockBlob.Uri.AbsoluteUri;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.Message;
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The  [HttpPostedFileBase manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfilebase.aspx) has this to say;

> FileName         Gets the fully qualified name of the file on the ***client***.

That is, the file name is not one that can be opened on the server.

I think what you really want to do is use the [InputStream property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfilebase.inputstream.aspx);

```cs
blockBlob.Properties.ContentType = file.ContentType;

blockBlob.UploadFromStream(file.InputStream);  // Upload from InputStream
return blockBlob.Uri.AbsoluteUri;
```

Answer (score 2):

Thank you so much: Joachim Isaksson (above) I spent the whole day yesterday fighting with this one line of code. I've voted your answer up but I thought I'd add a copy of your solution that lies within my own code now:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> UploadAsync()
{
    try
    {
        HttpFileCollectionBase files = Request.Files;
        int fileCount = files.Count;

        if (fileCount > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < fileCount; i++)
            {
                CloudBlockBlob blob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(GetRandomBlobName(files[i].FileName));

                blob.Properties.ContentType = files[i].ContentType;
                blob.UploadFromStream(files[i].InputStream);

                // the above 2 lines replace the following line from the downloaded example project:
                //await blob.UploadFromFileAsync(Path.GetFullPath(files[i].FileName), FileMode.Open);
            }
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you that helped me a lot, but it can be improved by using `await blob.UploadFromStreamAsync...` instead of  `blob.UploadFromStream...`